# Как настроить работу нескольких Pjax на одной странице при наличии его в модальных окнах?

Tags: php, yii2, инспекция-кода

Есть виджет, в котором отображается `GridView`, обёрнутый в `Pjax`. У грида есть пагинация. Этих виджетов на странице может быть много, а также при клике на какую-либо кнопку на странице - может подгрузиться модальное окно, в котором будет еще контент еще с одним набором этих виджетов.

При наличии виджетов **только** на обычной странице или **только** в модальном окне - проблем не возникает, потому что идентификаторы для контейнера `Pjax` и контейнера `GridView` генерируются автоматически (начиная с нуля) и пагинация работает по ним.

**Проблема**: Когда есть и то и то - в модальном окне идентификаторы начинаются опять с нуля (из-за особенностей работы PHP и новых запросов к серверу) и при клике на пагинацию в модальном окне - значения меняются в "обычном", а в модальном всё стоит на месте.

Выход: самому сделать генератор id для всего. Но опять же из-за особенностей работы PHP приходится задействовать сессию, как хранилище и ЖУУУУТКИЙ костыль. Прилагаю **рабочий** код ниже (главный метод - `init()`).

**Вопрос**: Как этот наиужаснейший код можно переделать в более адекватный? Возможно подскажите нормальное решение возникшей проблемы, более изящное.

Код виджета:

```
class MyWidget extends Widget {

    public $instanceId = 0;
    private static $modalInstancesStorage = [];
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @internal
     */
    public static $counter = 0;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static $autoIdPrefix = 'dc';
    // Другие свойства

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        /* 
        * Этот блок для отслеживания вида запроса 
        * и генерирования идентификатора на основе этих данных. 
        */
        $request = \Yii::$app->request;
        $isAjax = $request->isAjax;
        $isPjax = $request->headers->get('x-pjax');
        $containerIdParts = explode('-', $request->headers->get('x-pjax-container'));
        $containerIdNumber = end($containerIdParts);

        $id = 0;
        if (!$this->instanceId)
            $id = $this->getId();

        if ($isAjax && !$isPjax) {
            $id .= '1000';

            self::$modalInstancesStorage = \Yii::$app->session->get('myWidgetModal') ?? [];
            self::$modalInstancesStorage[$id] = serialize($this);
            \Yii::$app->session->set('myWidgetModal', self::$modalInstancesStorage);
        }

        if (strpos($containerIdNumber, '1000') !== false) {
            self::$modalInstancesStorage = \Yii::$app->session->get('myWidgetModal');
            $objectAsArray = (array)unserialize(self::$modalInstancesStorage[$containerIdNumber]);

            foreach($objectAsArray as $key => $value) {
                try {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                } catch (UnknownPropertyException $e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            $id = $containerIdNumber;
        }

        $this->instanceId = $id;
    }


    public function run() {
        $query = \Yii::createObject($this->srcModel)::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'forcePageParam' => false,
                'pageSizeParam' => false,
                'pageSize' => 3
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->render('widget-template', [        
            'instanceId' => $this->instanceId,  
             // Другие переменные
        ]);
    }

}
```

Представление:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'widget-grid-view-pjax-' . $instanceId]); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'my-grid-view-' . $instanceId,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,  
]); ?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: На досуге почитай про SOLID принципы. От многих головных болей они тебя избавят. Вот немного тут есть с примерами https://habr.com/ru/post/208442/

Comment: @fedornabilkin я знаю про SOLID. Этот код был на коленке собран, чтобы хоть как-то он работал. Мне, конечно, в данном случае хотелось бы именно решить проблему какими-то штатными средствами, нежели придумывать красивую обёртку для того, что есть. Но,  видимо, это невозможно. А отрефакторить в правильный код я знаю как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код даже в редактор скопировал, чтобы понять задумку :) Возможно мне не хватает данных для полного понимания картины, но тем не менее даже по этому кусочку кода можно прогнозировать адскую боль при дальнейшей разработке приложения.

Предлагаю попробовать сделать так:

1. Если виджет отображает данные, то пусть он их и отображает. Больше не надо в него добавлять код, который не относится к отображению данных.
2. Не надо тягать массивы в сессию и обратно, для этого есть кэш. В сессию кладем ключ кэша, если без сессии никак не обойтись.
3. Никто же нас не ограничивает в создании новых классов? Тогда создаем что-то типа MyWidgetManager, который и будет разруливать айдишниками.

В итоге получим чистенький виджет, отдельный класс для определения айдишника и будем устанавливать его (айдишник) при вызове виджета. В виджете в init() останется только вызвать setId();.

PS: так и не понял, для чего сериализовать объект и сохранять его.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас что-то попытаюсь сделать. `так и не понял, для чего сериализовать объект и сохранять его.` - Я не знаю как так происходит, но если вызывать код в модальном окне, то во время пагинации происходит странная ситуация: берутся свойства самого первого виджета. И gridview становится клоном первого) Остальные также. Предполагаю, что т.к. при открытии в модальном окне происходит ajax запрос - инициализируются все виджеты (например 3 шт.), а при пагинации в модалке pjax не может определить кто вызывал, делает инициализацию первого, берет его данные, подставляет и успокаивается

Comment: Придумал решение короче. Как ответ написал. Теперь мучений будет поменьше)

Answer (score 0):

Придумал более короткое решение.

```
$pathInfoParts = explode('/', \Yii::$app->request->pathInfo);
// анализ на вхождение 'index', потому что урл может его и не содержать изначально
// например /city, а потом запрос идет в /city/index
if ($pathInfoParts[count($pathInfoParts) - 1] === 'index') 
    array_pop($pathInfoParts);

$uniqueId = implode('-', $pathInfoParts) . self::$counter++;
```

При обычных решениях (не в виджетах) в `id` pjax'a и gridview автоматом добавляется строка контроллер-экшн. Получается примерно так `контроллер-экшн-p0`. Поэтому конфликтов для обычных страниц нет. Только для виджетов, у которых нет контроллера и обращения к методу. Поэтому как выход анализировать текущий `request` и на его основе формировать идентификатор по такому же принципу.

Comment: Может это и лучше в конкретном случае, но делать виджет зависимым от урла, не самая лучшая идея. Если они конфликтуют между собой, то там и надо решать проблему. Если сделать им одного родителя и в нем статикой хранить айдишники?

Comment: @fedornabilkin дело в том, что если делать тоже самое не в виджете а отдельно гридами с пиджаксами во вьюхах, то там как раз автоматом в идентификатор подставляется такой формат: `контроллер-метод-автоПрефикс-счётчик` (код для пробы: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/282bb6cd9f3437e42e23800951b202e4d4b5386b). Я лишь взял это за идею. Виджет не зависит от урла, он генерит изначальный префикс, основанный на урл.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Один родитель со статикой не катит, уже пробовал. Ведь виджет - сам по себе родитель у которого есть статическое поле `$counter` и `$autoPrefixId`. Но счётчик обнуляется в модалке из-за...ну понятно почему)) Поэтому изначально я начал манипуляции с сессией и прочие ужасы

Comment: Вот я сейчас был удивлен. В контроллере два практически одинаковых метода. Значит датапровайдера вынести в отдельный метод. Во вьюшке много логики, спрятать в виджет. Можно сделать свой и унаследовать его от юишного. Живой js во вьюхе приносит несчастью, сразу его в asset затолкать.

Comment: @fedornabilkin  Код из песочницы я применять в таком виде конечно не собираюсь) это был лишь пример, чтобы наглядно показать как генерируется идентификатор у виджетов на самом деле. Не более того)) Вот такие пироги))